# How to speed up loading 20k lines tsv-file with complex numbers?

Tags: performance-tuning, import, tsv-format

I have a long (20k lines) file which looks like this:

```
[...]
1.96    -0.03   (433.489,0) (-13408.6,212.4)    (0,421.9)   (433.489,0)
1.96    -0.02   (163.961,0) (-13423.2,5212.2)   (13423.2,0) (163.961,0)
1.96    -0.01   (-105.342,0)    (-13436.4,0)    (13436.4,0) (-105.342,-0.4124)
1.96    0   (-374.421,0)    (-13448.3,0)    (13448.3,0) (-374.421,42.12)
1.96    0.01    (-643.276,0)    (-13458.9,0)    (0, -129.479)   (-643.276,0)
1.96    0.02    (-911.905,-0.421)   (-13468.1,9912.23)  (13468.1,0) (-911.905,0)
[...]
```

The first two numbers are floating point numbers, the rest of them are tuples, where the first number is the real part and the second number the imaginary one.

I have put together the following solution:

```
convert2complex[lst_, index_] := 
 Flatten@{lst[[1 ;; index]], 
   Complex @@ 
      Interpreter["Number"][StringSplit[#, "(" | ")" | ","]] & /@ 
    lst[[index + 1 ;;]]}

amplitude["D1232_scattering"] = 
  convert2complex[#, 2] & /@ 
   Drop[Import["data/amplitude_D1232_scattering.tsv"], 1];
```

The `index` parameter basically tells the function where the strings begin (since the first two numbers need not be transformed).

I'd like to speed this up. I can change the format of the input file, if there is a better input format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one way to tackle your problem:

1. Import the file as a string

```
rawData = Import["C:\\data.tsv", "String"];
```

2. Remove `(`,`)` and replace `,` with `\t` and continuous spaces with `\t` (used [`FixedPoint`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FixedPoint.html) to make sure nothing is left)

```
data = Rest@
   ImportString[
    FixedPoint[
     StringReplace[#, {"," -> "\t", "(" -> "", ")" -> "", 
        RegularExpression@"\)? +\(?" -> "\t", 
        RegularExpression@"\t+" -> "\t"}] &, rawData], "TSV"];
```

3. Make the specified parts Imaginary and build the output

```
temp = {1, 1, 1, I, 1, I, 1, I, 1, I} * Transpose[data];

result = Transpose[Join[temp[[;; 2]], temp[[3 ;; ;; 2]] + temp[[4 ;; ;; 2]]]]
```

Check the result:

```
Dimensions[result]

(* Out: {6, 6} *)


result[[1, 4]]

(* Out: -13408.6 + 212.4 I *)
```

Comment: Since I can control the tsv format, I guess it'd be even faster to do the transformations in the C++ code that generates it and only start from step 3, right?

Comment: @infinitezero Yes, that would be faster (you'll still need the `Rest @ ImportString[ ... , "TSV"]` from step 2).

Comment: @infinitezero If you have control over the output, you could already output in Mathematica format.

Comment: I used this solution ( and customized it a bit to account for various key lengths in the beginning), but this gave a whopping speedup of factor 250 (my version took 200s, this took 0.8 seconds).

Comment: @infinitezero Glad to hear it. If you have full control over format, as rhermans suggest, you can write something like `{ {1, 1+2*I , ... } }`, then use [`ToExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToExpression.html) to parse it (although you should beware of security).

Comment: @BenIzd or directly `Get`.

Answer (score 5):

Here I offer two solutions, **Sol 1** is twice as fast as the one by *@BenIzd*, and **Sol 2** is twice as slow.

## Sol 1

This one is very fast

```
With[
    {
        path = "data/amplitude_D1232_scattering.tsv",
        tf = Join[#[[1;;2]], Apply[Complex,Partition[#[[3;;-1]],2],{1}] ]&
    },
tf/@Import[
       File[path]
       ,"Table"
       ,"FieldSeparators"->{","," ","∖t","(",")"}
    ]
]
```

[image]

## Sol 2

Alternatively, a similar by much slower solution

```
With[
    {
        tf = BlockMap[Apply[Complex], Insert[#, 0, {{2},{3}}], 2]&
    },
tf/@Import[
    File[path]
    ,"Table"
    ,"FieldSeparators"->{","," ","∖t","(",")"}
    ]
]
```

Comment: @infinitezero I find that *Sol 1* is significantly faster than the solution by Ben Izd.